# Metro8 Sqlite Select query

Tags: sqlite, microsoft-metro

I'm having problem with an SqLite and metro8 application. How can i execute a query (Select) on the SqLite database?

Insert work fine (its just db.Insert(something)), but have no idea how to select values that where  just inserted.

`var db1 = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath);`

there is a method called :

`db1.Execute(TableMapping map, string query, params object[] args)`

But what are the tablemapping and params arguments in that method?

Thank you for any answer!

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633936/select-query-of-sqlite-in-metro-app and this link: 

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is using a SQLiteDatabase and the sqlite-net.1.0.5 NuGet package...

We do selects like this:

```
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _asyncConnection;

    public async Task<IList<string>> ReadIds()
    {
        List<MyDataType> result = await _asyncConnection.Table<MyDataType>().ToListAsync();
            return result.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    }
```

or:

```
    public async Task<int> ReadCount(int id)
    {
        return await _asyncConnection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(
               String.Format("select COUNT(*) from MyDataType where Id == '{0}'", id));
    }
```