# Select query of sqlite in metro app?

Tags: wpf, sqlite, select, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have seen quite a number of examples describing the usage of SQLite in Metro app. Most of the examples have either Orderby/Insert/Delete statements. May I know how do I get the data from a pre-populated db using the Select statement?

Secondly, how does someone store the data into an array or arrayList after the execution of the query?

Kindly help me with this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this example is what you're looking for:

```
return db.runAsync('SELECT * FROM Table');
```

[Here is a pretty useful article on it.](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Extending the example to C#:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("people");
var query = conn.Table<Person>().Select();
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm coding in C# and unfortunately I don't know the Java style which is used there.

Comment: @WiniP Updated with code that should work. It's for async connection to sqlite, however it can be easily changed to sync by changing the connection type.